# How to use if..else condition withing <div> tag in cshtml?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to use `if else` condition within `<div>` tag to display/hide `title`. What is happening is, sometimes `@tag.Description` is empty and because of that my HTML shows empty `title` and I do not want that.

[image]

I want to only display `title` if `@tag.Description` is not empty otherwise do not show it.

I've added the condition but want to make that it is the right approach.

Code:

```
<ul class="tag-summary">
    @foreach (var tag in Model.MenuTags)
    {
        <li>
            //Current
            <div class="tag @tag.TagValue" title="@tag.Description">
                <label>@tag.Name</label>
            </div>

            // Code with condition but not sure this is the right way or not
            <div class="tag @tag.TagValue" title="(string.IsNullOrEmpty(@tag.Description) ? null : @tag.Description)">
                <label>@tag.Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="tag-definition">@tag.Description</div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: do it like in place of title tag @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag.Description) ? "" : "'title':tag.Description "

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

```
<ul class="tag-summary">
    @foreach (var tag in Model.MenuTags)
    {
        <li>
            <div class="tag @tag.TagValue" **title='@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag.Description) ? null : tag.Description)'**>
                <label>@tag.Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="tag-definition">@tag.Description</div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```